# User Interaction interrupted after UIVIew block animations

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview

As expected (and desired in my case) user interaction is disabled during block based UIView animations. The problem I encounter is if the user attempts to make a selection (tap a `UIButton`, select a `UITableViewCell`) during the animation, once it completes it takes 2-3 taps sometimes before the app to become responsive to taps again.

What is the problem?

Comment: Perhaps you could post the animation code you're using? That might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction in options mask.

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

Comment: What if I don't want user interaction to be enabled during the animation?

Comment: I think this is the only way. Because all user interactions are blocked during animations without this flag.